# How to check differentiability of any function?

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x)=\tan(\pi[x])$, where $[x]$ is the greatest integer function. Is $f$ differentiable at all $x$?

If yes then its graph will be?

If not then at which x it is not differentiable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you even differentiate, consider what your function is using the identity $\tan \beta = \frac{\sin \beta}{\cos \beta}$,

$$ f(x) = \tan (\pi [x]) = \frac{\sin (\pi [x])}{\cos (\pi [x])} = 0$$

We know this because sine is 0 at integer multiples of $\pi$, $\sin (\pi [x]) = \sin (\pi n) = 0 \,\, (\forall n\in \mathbb Z)$. Finally, $\frac{d}{dx} (0) = 0$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

1. What do you think of the differentiability of $g(x) = [x]$ and so too $h(x) = \pi[x]$?
2. What happens when you consider $\tan(h(x))$?

Comment: I think it is differentiable at all x. As the function is becoming zero at all x..

Comment: @JaySaha correct :)